# Laravel 5.2 not logout

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'am using authentification in my Laravel 5.2 application. All ok, but logout not working. Can anyone explain to me, why it happend?

routes.php

```
Route::group([

    'middleware' => ['web']

], function () {

        Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
        Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
        Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
        ...
});
```

Controller.php

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout', 'getLogout']);
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        /* This place not trigger */
        echo 'Logout';
        exit;

        Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->logout();

        return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/');
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this is work

You make a mistake in the method name of the controller.

**1)**

```
  public function logout()
```

Replace with this method

```
 public function getLogout()
```

Explanation ----------------------------------------

In route you used following route

```
Auth\AuthController@getLogout
```

And you used a Method following

```
public function logout()
```

method name is only logout and route has getLogout so the this method not find in the Auth controller so logout not working.

---

**2)**
Another way is use this only.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);          
}
```

And Remove the Logout method.

Thnaks

Comment: You right of course, thanks. But some addition, this line must be such as `$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout', 'getLogout']]);`.